# Permission Set issue

Tags: security, financialforce

I am writing to you in order to describe permission set issue that i don't know how to figure out.
I want to give an access to part of financial force package (possibility to assign current company and to approve purchase invoices) for some users who have Salesforce Platform licence. I created a permission set where I added access to:

- "Accounting" application
- all finacial force visualforce pages
- all financial force apex classes
- Company, UserCompany and Purchase Invoice objects and tabs

The strange thing is that I assigned the same permission set to two users with the same license and profile. One user has access to these components and second doesn't. Do you know what can be the reason of this issue?

User who has access to the components:
[image: User who has access to the components]

User who is assigned to the same permission set but doesn't have access to the components:
[image: User who is assigned to the same permission set but doesn't have access to the components]

Comment: If they have identical profile, licence type, there should be no reason for differing experience.  However, they have differing Roles.  What is the experience the two users are having?  Is it a missing App?  Are they unable to find the Tab in the customizer?  That will help us help you.

Comment: I changed Frederik role to the same that has Ilmarin, but it was the same. Frederik cannot change application to "Accounting", doesn't see tabs and visualforce page that is stored on the left side bar. Ilmarin sees all of these things.

Comment: As strange as this sounds, you're absolutely sure that the permission set is assigned to both users?  Additionally, can you post screen shots of the experience the users are having?  I might help us figure this out.